# Waiter ImageScanComplete failed: ECR Image Scan failing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd, amazon-ecr

Hope you are all doing well! I am running into an issue in my Jenkins pipeline when I try to use the **aws ecr wait image-scan-complete** command.

This is my Jenkins pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        AWS_CREDENTIALS = credentials('AWSCredentials')
    }
    stages {

        stage('Build Docker Image'){
            steps{
                dir("$CODE_CHECKOUT_FOLDER"){
                    sh 'sudo docker compose build --no-cache'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Scan ECR Image'){
            steps{
                dir("$CODE_CHECKOUT_FOLDER"){
                    script{
                        withAWS(credentials:'AWSCredentials', region: 'us-west-2'){
                            //Grab the imageDigest of the latest image with the tag test
                            def digest_image = sh(
                                script: "aws ecr describe-images --repository-name testrepo --image-ids imageTag=test --query 'imageDetails[0].imageDigest'", 
                                returnStdout: true
                            ).trim()

                            // Wait for the image scan to complete
                            sh "aws ecr wait image-scan-complete --repository-name testrepo --image-id imageDigest=$digest_image"

                            def scan_findings = sh(
                                script: "aws ecr describe-image-scan-findings --repository-name testrepo --image-id imageDigest=$digest_image",
                                returnStdout: true
                            ).trim()
                            writeFile file: IMAGE_SCAN_FINDINGS, text: scan_findings
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to ECS'){
            steps{
                dir("$CODE_CHECKOUT_FOLDER"){
                    sh "sudo aws ecs update-service --region us-west-2 --cluster testrepo-dev-cluster --service testrepo-dev-service --force-new-deployment"
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    post{
        always{
            cleanWs()
            echo "Cleaned up the workspace and finished executing pipeline!"
        }
    }
}
```

All my pipeline is doing is building a docker image, then uploading this image to ECR. I then want to wait for the ecr image scan to complete, so I can attach the findings of the ECR scan into the email body.

**Currently, the pipeline is failing with the following error message:**

Waiter ImageScanComplete failed: An error occurred (ScanNotFoundException): Image scan does not exist for the image with '{imageDigest:'IMAGE_DIGEST_HERE', imageTag:'test'}' in the repository with name 'testrepo' in the registry with id 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

**This is what I have tried so far:**

1. Instead of using imageDigest in the ecr wait image scan complete step, I tried using the imageTag instead. That also produces the same error message.
2. When I run these commands directly on the linux serving running my Jenkins instances on a n **old** build, it works as expected and the ecr wait image scan complete command does not fail.
3. I have made sure the aws cli version is the latest one which is v2.

At this point I'm not sure what could be causing this issue. Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What's working for me right now is to make use of a sleep() step before the ecr wait scan image command. Feel like this really defeats the purpose of the ecr wait step. Hoping to get a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue here. Didn’t look like this is working as intended. Better try a custom script to poll the scan status for “COMPLETED” and use describe-image-scan-findings and query the result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Below the logic should follow to achieve the end result

**Logic**

(1)Docker Build > (2)Push to ECR > (3)Start the Scan > (4)Wait for ECR to complete Scan

**Commands**

```
(1)docker compose build --no-cache

(2)docker push <REPO URL>:<TAG>

(3)aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name <REPO-NAME> --image-id imageTag=<TAG>

(4)aws ecr wait image-scan-complete --repository-name <REPO-NAME> --image-id imageTag=<TAG>
```

Command (4) is relevant only if (3) got initiated in the past. That means if you run (4) without (3) you see the same error like you reported